# bluetooth don't work in my app Android 6.0(API 23) to Android 7.0(API 24)

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have a problem with bluetooth in my Android application.

When I build my application with "API 23: Android 6.0" and less, the Bluetooth  works. However, when I build my application with "API 24: Android 7.0" and more, Bluetooth does not work.

I use Android Studio 3.0.

Comment: I think some more information will be required to there can be a useful answer. Maybe you can share some details and code snippets?

Comment: I am ready to share more information

Comment: Then you should do so add add this information to your question.

Comment: like what, I'm a beginner so I do not know what information do you want me to be with you

Comment: Please check: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).